# I need help to check if my solution to an expected value of discrete random variable problem is correct.

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics, random-variables

The problem statement says:

*An urn contains balls numbered 1, 2, 3. First a ball is drawn from the urn, and then a fair coin is tossed the number of times as the number shown on the drawn ball. Fin the expected number of heads.*

Now, what I have done so far is calculate the p.d.f for the problem as follows:

$H= $The drawn of head in all tosses of the coin

$P(X=1|H) = \frac{\text{# Of favorable cases}}{\text{# Of all cases}} = \frac{1}{3}*\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{6}$

$P(X=2|H) = \frac{1}{3}*\frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{12}$

$P(X = 3 |H) = \frac{1}{3} * \frac{1}{8} = \frac{1}{24}$

Then I use the general formula for the Expected value in a discrete :

$\sum_{k = 1}^3{k*p(k)}=1*\frac{1}{6}+ 2*\frac{1}{12} + 3*\frac{1}{24} = \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{8} = \frac{11}{24}$

Now, this doesn't seem right to me, but I don't know why, I want to know what I'm doing wrong if I'm doing something wrong at all.

Comment: You are not computing the expected number of heads. You have computed the expected number of heads when all tosses are head.

Comment: Okay, but in that case how would I compute the expected number of heads? I thought that once I had the p.d.f I just had to implement the expected value equation to obtain the problem. I guess that the problem is in how I calculate the p.d.f but then how could I do it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to calculate the probability to obtain *once head* for instance:

$N:=$ Ball with number N has been drawn, $H:=$ H is the number of heads

*Law of total probabilty*

$P(H=1)=P(H=1|N=1)\cdot P(N=1)+P(H=1|N=2)\cdot P(N=2)+P(H=1|N=3)\cdot P(N=3)$

$=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{3}+\frac{3}{8}\cdot \frac{1}{3}$

It might be helpful to know that in general $P(H=k|N=n)=\binom{n}{k}\cdot 0.5^n$

---

You calculate $P(H=2)$ and $P(H=3)$ in the same way. Finally you calculate the expected value. This is indeed

$$E(H)=\sum_{k=1}^3 k\cdot P(H=k)$$

Comment: But in $P(H=1|N=2)$ wouldn't be $\frac{3}{4}$? Since I have only one case where I don't get at least a head in the toss(When I get two tails).

Comment: @JorgeRodríguez $P(H=1|N=2)$ has nothing to do with "at least" It is the probability you get  exact  one head, given number two has been drawn. You toss two times a coin. There are two ways to get exact one head (out of 4): $HT,  \ TH$

Comment: Oh! I got it! Thank you very much!

Comment: @JorgeRodríguez You´re welcome.